# Efficient way to do self join with minimum support?

Tags: algorithms, python, data-mining

In the apriori algorithm there's the self join step,

So, say we have

```
1 3
2 3 
3 5 
2 5
```

If I were to do an exhaustive join I'd end up with a tuple including (1, 3, 5) - although (1, 5) has no support. What's an efficient way to only get the wanted result of (2, 3, 5)?

I had a look at the geeksforgeeks explanation, but they seem to do a step of computing all the combinations and then going back and checking if each subset in the combination has support... But, that seems like an unnecessary step.

This is what I have at the moment:

```python
    def get_possible_combinations(self, k):
        # Where itemset is a dict with keys being item and value
        # the item count
        keys = list(self.itemset)
        if(k == 2):
            # If we're at k=2, we just have a straight up list of
            # keys to combine [1, 2, 3] => [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)]
            return combinations(keys, 2)
        # Join self.itemset with itself
        # HELP this is where I'm at a loss as to what to do
        key_sets = list(map(set, sorted(keys)))
        combos = set()
        for i_item in key_sets:
            for j_item in key_sets[1:]:
                union = sorted(i_item.union(j_item))
                if len(union) == k:
                    combos.add(tuple(union))
        return combos
```

Given my current solution, completely disregarding apriori is faster than actually calculating those `get_possible_combinations`

Comment: I can't tell what task you are trying to solve.  Please specify the input and the desired output in a self-contained way.  An example is not a substitute for a clear specification of the problem.  We're not a coding site, and code is off-topic here.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70027874/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145902/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).